# Determine if the following function is one-to-one and/or onto

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, transformation

$T(x,y,z) = (xy,yz,xz)$
For one to one, I made $(x,y,z)=(u,v,w)$ and solved.

$$xy=uv\to y=\frac{uv}{x}$$

$$\frac{uz}{x}=w$$

$$xz = uw \to x = u$$

$$uy = uv \to y = v$$

$$vz = vw \to z = w$$

So since every $(x,y,z)$ maps to a unique point $(u,v,w)$, $T(x,y,z)$ is one-to-one. Correct?

However, I'm not sure how to prove that the function is onto.
I know that $T(D*) = D$, and  $T\vec x = A\vec x$ where A is a $3\times3$ matrix such that $\det(A) \neq 0$. But I don't know how to work with this to solve without having some points to work with. By looking at the function, I am pretty sure that it is onto because every point in D* will map to somewhere in D. But that's not sufficient. Could I chose arbitrary points and make equations out of it and solve those? For example:

$$\begin{bmatrix}a & b & c\\d & e &f\\g &h&i\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}u\\v\\w\end{bmatrix}$$

$$ax+by+cz = u$$

$$dx+ey+fz = v$$

$$gx+hy+iz = w$$

Then choose arbitrary points for $x,y,z$ and note that from earlier $u=x,v=y,w=z$.
Then solve. But, T is already given, so this may be futile. Any help?

Comment: I changed $3x3$ to $3\times3$ and $det$ to $\det$ and ----> to $\to$, and set some things in "display" rather than "inline", and also changed some rather weird MathJax code to something standard. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Do you think that the function is a linear transformation?

Comment: I'm not sure, I haven't ever taken linear algebra and I'm not currently. This topic briefly came up in vector calculus and I don't really like it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**

With respect to be one-to-one:

$$T(1,0,0)=(0,0,0)=T(0,0,1)\implies \cdots$$

With respect to be onto:

Try to solve $T(x,y,z)=(-1,1,1).$ That is, $(xy,yz,xz)=(-1,1,1).$ $xz>0$ means $x$ and $z$ have the same sign. $yz>0$ means $y$ and $z$ have the same sign. Is it possible $xy<0$ if both have the same sign?

Comment: Ah man, so it's not even one-to-one. I'm still not sure about how to go about proving/disproving onto though.

Comment: Was that point arbitrary or is there significance behind it?
And I ended up getting it down to x = $(-1)^(1/2), which doesn't exist. Was that your point?

Comment: ahh, no they are opposite signs, which completely contradicts the previous statements. So, T(x,y,z) is neither one-to-one nor onto. Thanks!

Comment: You can use the signs argument with any point of the form $(+,+,-)$ or $(+,-,+)$ or $(-,+,+).$ This is the significance behind it.